# Cross Reference problem

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, xr

I have a problem when I use a cross-reference from other files. I have a folder in which there is a `main.tex` file and a subfolder (Chapter) containing `Chapter1.tex` and `Chapter2.tex`.

In the main file, I include only the chapter files like this:

```
    \include{Chapters/Chapter1}
    \include{Chapters/Chapter2}
```

My problem is that in the `Chapter2.tex` file I need to reference a section from Chapter1.

**Chapter1.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\label{ch:first_chapter}

\section{first section}\label{sc:first_section}
     some Text..........
\end{document}
```

**Chapter2.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[C1-]{/Chapter1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\label{ch:second_chapter}
\section{section}\label{sc:first_section_ch2}

 Some text...text \ref{C1-sc:first_section}
 \end{document}
```

When I compile the file, only `??` appears.

Comment: I don't think `\chapter` is defined for the standalone document class. Besides this, for me this sounds more like a job for https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles?lang=en then for `standalone`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `\chapter` is defined for the standalone document class. Besides this, for me this sounds more like a job for the `subfiles` package then for `standalone`:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
   \subfile{chapter1}
   \subfile{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

and chapter1.tex

```
% !TeX root = chapter1.tex 
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\label{ch:first_chapter}

\section{first section}\label{sc:first_section}
     some Text..........
\end{document}
```

and chapter2.tex

```
% !TeX root = chapter2.tex 
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{main}}{}{%
    \externaldocument{chapter1}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\label{ch:second_chapter}
\section{section}\label{sc:first_section_ch2}

 Some text...text \ref{sc:first_section}
\end{document}
```

(the above example assumes that all 3 files are in the same folder, for the usage of subfolders, you have to adjust the paths of the main file and the chapter files accordingly)

Comment: What does this do? `\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{main}}{}{%
    \externaldocument{chapter1}
}`

Comment: @Mars This only loads the `\externaldocument` if the subfile is compiled. If this would be loaded when the main file is compiled, it would result in an error of labels defined multiple times.

Comment: If there were a third chapter, would we add `\externaldocument{chapter2}` right after `\externaldocument{chapter1}`?

Comment: @RobertWolfe Correct. The order does not matter, you could add the second before the first

Answer (score 2):

The `/` before `Chapter1` in `\externaldocument` is wrong. Also `standalone` does not have the `\chapter` command.

In my point of view, there is nothing to gain to make separate documents from the individual chapter files here.

Both (or all!) files should use `hyperref` packages in order to provide the correct label format.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\label{ch:first_chapter}

\section{first section}\label{sc:first_section}
     some Text..........
\end{document}
```

Chapter2.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[C1-]{Chapter1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\label{ch:second_chapter}
\section{section}\label{sc:first_section_ch2}

Some text...text \ref{C1-sc:first_section}
\end{document}
```