# External document cross-referencing not working

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles, xr

I am having trouble getting cross-referencing to work. I am using the package `xr-hyper`. I have a 'main' file called `main.tex` and two `subfiles` called `intro.tex` (Introduction) and `app.tex` (Appendix A). I want to refer to an equation defined in `intro.tex` in Appendix A.

Either I have made an error in my code or its an issue with my build process. I am very confused about the build process for this. I'm using TeXstudio and I have set up my build process to run PdfLaTeX two times, which I do on `main.tex`. Is this correct?

I *once* got the numbers to appear correctly, but I'm not sure how I managed this. But, when I then added a new chapter ahead of `intro.tex`, the numbers of the references in Appendix A did not update when I re-built the file `main.tex`.

Any advice would be much appretiated.

The errors I am getting are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### **`main.tex`**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subfile{intro.tex}

\begin{appendices}
\subfile{app.tex}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

### **`intro.tex`**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:newton}
F = ma
\end{equation}
Equation~\ref{eqn:newton}

\end{document}
```

### **`app.tex`**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\externaldocument[I-]{intro} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Talking about Equation~\ref{I-eqn:newton}}
Let's refer to Equation~\ref{I-eqn:newton}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you compile `intro` before `app`?

Comment: I didn't realise I *had* to compile `intro` and `app` in the first place, before compiling `main.tex`

Comment: Weirdly, when I try to compile to `intro` and `app`, TeXstudio instead compiles `main`. But, if I restart TeXstudio and open `intro` and `app` without opening `main` then I can get TeXstudio to compile `intro` and `app` individually. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Personally I find your system a bit risky. If you changed something between compiling intro and your final document, the reference in the appendix might be wrong. Personally I use the external labels without prefix and only in the subfile, not in the main document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378163/36296 for my system

Comment: Yes, texstudio automatically tries to detect the main document, so you have to manually define the root document when compiling subfiles. See the first lines in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378163/36296

Comment: @samcarter Thank you!! Your solution works perfectly! In fact, it seems to work too well :) I have one question. Say I have `intro` and `app` saved in individual subfolders. If I write `\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{main}}{}{%\externaldocument{intro}}` in `app.tex` this works fine *even* when `intro.tex` is saved in a subfolder. Why does this work? I thought I might have to tell it where to find `intro`.

Comment: Good question, I never tried that - subfolders just make everything more difficult :)